# Codename One Swipeable Container half closing

Tags: codenameone

I am using Swipeable Container in my app, and have noticed recently that I can now leave it at half closed by slowly swiping it closed but stopping before it gets all the way closed. When this happens, it seems to mess up the display, and allows for swiping to the right, even though I have no component for the left hand side.

`Container c = new MoveListContainer(movesToDisplay.get(i));
SwipeableContainer swipeableContainer = new SwipeableContainer(null,
                                new BottomSwipeContainer(movesToDisplay.get(i)), c) ;`

Any idea why this might be happening or how I can make sure it always closes all the way?
Thanks.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this although it only happens occasionally. Do you have an approximate date when this behavior started showing? Can you please file an issue on that?

Comment: Issue opened : #2308
Same code last built in June 30th, doesn't seem to have the issue. First noticed this in November 2017

Comment: Ugh, it might be hard to track it as far back to then. I'll try to assign it to 4.0 even though it's a pretty packed release by now